# Chrome Extension: Port Error

Tags: google-chrome-extension, port

first of all I'm at first approach with Chrome Extension.
I'm trying to make a communication between the contentscript.js and the background.html but I get this error:

> Port error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist. miscellaneous_bindings:235
>   chromeHidden.Port.dispatchOnDisconnect

Here are the pieces of code:

manifest.json
http://pastebin.com/FFk3PEs3

contentscript.js
http://pastebin.com/dwK9vrTB

background.js
http://pastebin.com/Zudw4DZb

I don't get why the port error occures and looking on the development section of chrome I don't even find info about sendRequest, but just sendMessage... is sendRequest deprecated?
I've read about the inline JS not executed and changed the manifest bust still got the error.

Mind that this is a piece of code not written by me, but I'm playing with it to learn how to make extensions.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Where's the error showing up? (background page or content script?). And yes, sendRequest is deprecated.

Comment: I think in the contentscript

Comment: links given by you, are not visible http://pastebin.com/FFk3PEs3, can you please post your code here..

Answer (score -1):

Replaced the sendRequest with sendMessage and onRequest with sendRequest and everything works!